# Aggregated query for overlapping days in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm creating a database structure for an almost realtime statistical module. I would like to count user behavior for different products: new likes, votes, new comments and total activity (sum of votes, likes, etc).

The module needs to send back the most *active* N products for the last 8, 16 or 24 hours. 
My first idea was the following schema for a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e37d0db8c0897d651509c"),
    "date" : "2016-04-13",
    "trackId" : 35,
    "count" : {
        "hour_1" : {
            "total" : 120,
            "downVote" : 35,
            "newComment" : 26,
            "upVote" : 34,
            "like" : 25
        },
        "hour_2" : {
            "total" : 124,
            "downVote" : 32,
            "like" : 28,
            "upVote" : 33,
            "newComment" : 31
        },
        // ...
        "hour_24" : {
            "total" : 119,
            "downVote" : 42,
            "newComment" : 30,
            "upVote" : 31,
            "like" : 16
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I have X documents for X products in a day and with this query I can fetch the data what I need vey quickly.

```
db.getCollection('HourlyStat')
  .aggregate([
    {$match: {date: '2016-04-13'}}, 
    {
      $project: {'trackId': "$trackId", 
      count: {
        $sum: ["$count.hour_1.total", "$count.hour_2.total", ..., "$count.hour_8.total"] } 
      } 
    }, 
    {$sort: {'count': -1}}, {$limit: 10}
  ])
```

Unfortunately, this is not usable for time periods what include two days. 
For example: from `2016-04-13 12:00:00` to `2016-04-14 12:00:00`

Can I write a query for this or I should change my data structure? An easy workaround would be to store hourly data in independent documents but it would contain 24 times more data, and for a huge number of products, it can be slow.

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need to run multiple aggregation queries for each time slot and merge returned documents in your application.

Comment: @Saleem That is not an acceptable solution, because in that case, the application server needs to process a lots of data what is memory consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your schema as you suggest for the hourly data in independent documents.  You should also use proper Date() fields for your dates, which will allow you to be a lot more flexible with your date-based queries.

```
db.getCollection('HourlyStat')
  .aggregate([
    {$match: {date: {$gt: new Date(new Date()-1000*60*60*24 )}}}
    //...
    ])
```

If it's easier, you could also generate the start end times of your search on the client, rather than limiting to the last n hours, for example.  That has the advantage of a simpler looking query (and I like simple queries)

```
db.getCollection('dates')
  .aggregate([
    {$match: {date: {$gte: ISODate("2016-04-13T09:00:00.000+0000"), $lt: ISODate("2016-05-16T20:00:00.000+0000") }}}
    ])
```